# JQuery nextAll prevail each function non return

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The following code was designed to apply a procedure to all the child elements of containers before and after the one being clicked. It is broken in some way. I have never used nextAll or prevAll so it is probably related to bad coding.

```
$('.bounceholder ul').prevAll().each(function(){
            $(this + ' li').each(function(){
                $(this).animate({left: -200, top:-8, leaveTransforms:true}, 600);
            });
        });


        $('.bounceholder ul').nextAll().each(function(){
            $(this + ' li').each(function(){
                $(this).animate({left: +1000, top:-8, leaveTransforms:true}, 600);
            });
        });
```

Where's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $('.bounceholder ul').prevAll().each(function() {
        $('li', this).animate({left: -200, top:-8, leaveTransforms:true}, 600);
    });


    $('.bounceholder ul').nextAll().each(function(){
        $('li', this).animate({left: +1000, top:-8, leaveTransforms:true}, 600);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A good answer has already been given (using `this` as a context rather than trying to concatenate it with the string `li`) but you could use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) as a shorter alternative:

```
$('.bounceholder ul').siblings().each(function() {
    $('li', this).animate({left: -200, top:-8, leaveTransforms:true}, 600);
});
```

As `prevAll` returns all the preceding siblings, and `nextAll` returns all the following siblings of the selected element, `siblings` should provide exactly the same functionality but only requires the one block of code.